# How to display action result of iframe in parent window

Tags: html, iframe, forms, html-frames

I have a html page.
html page has a iframe.
when I submit the form inside iframe, returned result is displayed inside that iframe.
How to display that result in parent of iframe??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#test").load(function (e) {
                var htmlFromServer = $(e.target).contents().find("html").html();
            });
        });
    </script>

  <iframe id="test" src="HTMLPage1.htm"></iframe>
```

All you need to do is handle the onload event of the iframe. This event is triggered when the iframe receives response from the server.